# How to capture network consumption for a series of IP's + linux +?

Tags: linux, centos, networking, traffic

I am looking for a method to capture the network consumption ( not bandwidth ) on daily basis for a range of IP's. Lets say { 192.168.122.0/25 }.

I want to calculate per day how much traffic/data consumed by these range of IP's . This is just for our validation purpose, to know how much KB/MB/GB/'s of data consumed by each IP's on daily basis.

My environment is RHEL/Centos 7,

Would you please suggest any tools with option in order to achieve this operation?  If I find a way to track the usage/consumption, I will automate the process daily.

I am looking for CLI instead of graphical tools. Also, I tried with iptraf, nmap, iftop, but can't be able to find an option to take network consumption across the range of IP's.

Comment: Could you explain what you understand under "network consumption" as opposed to bandwidth usage? How is it different?

Comment: @dirkt the thing is that I want to calculate per day how much traffic/data consumed by these range of IP's . This is just for our validation purpose, to know  how much KB/MB/GB/'s of data consumed by each IP's on daily basis. I hope this answer your question

Comment: Please add new information by **editing** your question, not in comments. Comments are not guaranteed to be permanent. I've done the edit for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One tool that could suit your need is [tshark](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tshark):

```
$ tshark -q -i eth0 -a duration:86400 -z conv,ip net 192.168.122.0/25
```

With:

- `-q`: don't display the continuous count of packets captured
- `-i eth0`: capture traffic on interface `eth0` (alternatively you can also use `-i any` to capture traffic on all interfaces)
- `-a duration:86400` : capture traffic for a day
- `-z conv,ip` : get IP statistics
- `net 192.168.122.0/25` : capture filter

Sample output:

```
$ tshark -q -i any -a duration:10 -z conv,ip net 192.168.134.0/24
                                               |       <-      | |       ->      | |     Total     |    Relative    |   Duration   |
                                               | Frames  Bytes | | Frames  Bytes | | Frames  Bytes |      Start     |              |

151.101.122.217      <-> 192.168.134.142          571     43915     591   3186555    1162   3230470     0,994980222         6,3748
192.168.134.142      <-> 192.168.136.27             5      1347       6       788      11      2135     5,714866377         0,0350
192.168.134.96       <-> 192.168.134.255            0         0      10      1060      10      1060     0,000000000         9,1583
151.101.129.69       <-> 192.168.134.142            5       608       5       632      10      1240     6,193916779         0,1324
```

From there, depending on your need, you can use other cli tools to parse the output and sum bytes (e.g. `awk`)

Comment: as I'm getting different values for each iteration. Do you have any other tools to be test like this ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "different values for each iteration".

Comment: What I meant the values which I getting the output for each IP, which is not progressing. As a test, I hit the above command 6 times per hour. Each iteration output gives me different results differing higher / lower..

Answer (score 0):

So you do want the network traffic **bandwidth usage**, but a daily summary.

You gave a private IP range, so I assume you want them by the IP address of your own machine, not by the IP address of internet hosts they connect to.

There are two ways in principle:

1) Monitor traffic on each machine. The kernel keeps packet counters for each network interface in `/proc`, so you can read those counters and calculate average/total traffic.

2) Monitor traffic on a central router. To sort these by local IP, you need more than total traffic, so you need to inspect packets. Many traffic monitoring tools work by using promiscious mode on a network interface; this may cause maesurable CPU load. Another option is to write custom `iptable` rules to count usage.

There's a *ton* of different tools available, see e.g. [here](https://blog.serverdensity.com/80-linux-monitoring-tools-know/) or [here](https://www.binarytides.com/linux-commands-monitor-network/) for some (and google for more, software recommendations are outside the scope of this stackexchange).

If you choose alternative 1, a popular protocol to gather information from all monitored hosts into a central place is [SNMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol), so include this in your google searches.

Comment: Thanks @dirkt . Here regarding #1, I don't have access to login each machine to capture the network usage from /proc. Reg #2, I'm planning to set in promiscious mode and capture the traffic. I never tried with SNMP. Do you have any best tools satisfying the criteria. Btw I'm checking from the link you posted one by one.

Comment: If you are doing it in a central location (variant #2), you don't need SNMP. I can't make any recommendation as for "best" tools, everyone has different requirements.